# Write own Java logic on https://restlet.com

Tags: java, restlet

I tried learning things via tutorials on https://restlet.com but unable to figure out whether can I write my own custom Java logic on https://restlet.com API?

All it allows is to download generated Java code.

Appreciate if you can guide/help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create your API and let APISpark host and run it for you?

Do you want to just develop your own Web server using the Restlet Framework ? In this case you can still use APISpark or the Studio in order to get a server skeleton that you will have to complete. You can also develop it manually by using the Restlet Framework.

Best regards,
Thierry Boileau